# Error: cyclic dependency detected in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

There is an object that I want to write into the DB. The object I want to write is IntervalID. It outputs an error when it is written:

```
(node:13376) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cyclic dependency detected
    at serializeObject (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Bot testa\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:333:34)
    at serializeInto (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Bot testa\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:941:17)
```

Code of command:

```
 const Command = require("../../Structures/Command");
 const mongoose = require("mongoose");
 const User = require("../../data/user");
 const Discord = require("discord.js");
 let trade;

        let data = await User.findOne({
        guildID: message.guild.id,
        userID: message.author.id,
        });
        trade = setInterval(() => tradechannel.send("Text"), 15000);
        data.tradeID = trade;
        data.save();
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you are trying to make query.

Comment: added some code of command